# Ionic command return undefined:1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

For 2 days now I can't do anything involving ionic.

Every command would return this:

```
$ ionic serve

undefined:1

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you resolve this?

Comment: Me too having the same issue did u find any solution ??

Comment: Please elaborate your question , or paste your controller which give this error so that we check this.. whats wrong their

Comment: I experienced this one before and this helps me a lot http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-framework-command-line-error-undefined-1-syntaxerror-unexpected-token/29123/6

Comment: do you have a github project I can take a look at? seeing your full code should help

Comment: go for a quick fix npm cache clean and the try again npm install -g ionic